# Windows: Copy files in remoted machine from that machine to local machine

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-desktop, powershell, file-transfer

I am on a Windows computer, say "*LocalA*". I manually RDP into a remote server, say "*RemoteB*". From *RemoteB* I run a script which does a bunch of things and at the end it should copy/send files from *RemoteB* to the machine from which I remoted, i.e. *LocalA*. **How can the copy part be achieved using powershell or similar program?**

Basically, I want to do something like this in powershell (or using any external command line tool):

```
# pseudo syntax
Copy -source RemoteB/C:/foo.txt -target LocalA/C:/foo.txt
# run from RemoteB
```

**However, *LocalA* and *RemoteB* are not on any shared network or domain**. They are totally unrelated machines. All I have with me is IP of *RemoteB*, the username and password.

I can of course manually pull a file from *RemoteB* to *LocalA*, using Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V. Basically I am trying to automate the manual copying.

Answer (score 1):

Option A : mount each others drive as its network drive and then copy/paste file as usual.

Option B (my favorite) : install an ftp server (I use ftpserverlite, and setup say.. D:\ drive + 1 account(UsrName&pswd) with all access + start server) > and the receiving side.. access it via command prompt using `ftp 10.5.4.8` (Assuming that is the receiving side IP) > enter UsrName > Enter pswd > use `get` and `put` command to either get files from server or put a local file into server. || use `quit` to exit ftp command & `ls` to list files.